# Get task id of scheduled task in celery

Tags: python, django, celery

I am scheduling a celery task in django using apply_async. I need to get the task ID when i schedule the task.

I need to get the task ID so that I can revoke the scheduled task if user chooses to cancel.

```
  def some_function:
      the_fn_to_be_called.apply_async(kwargs={my_arguments}, countdown=countdown_in_secs)
```

Answer (score 1):

`apply_async` returns an [AsyncResult](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult) which has an `id` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom task_id like below.

```
  from celery import uuid
 
  def some_function:
      task_id = uuid()

      // Do something with task_id

      the_fn_to_be_called.apply_async(kwargs={my_arguments}, countdown=countdown_in_secs, task_id=task_id)
```

or

```
  def some_function:

      // Do something with task_id
      async_result = the_fn_to_be_called.apply_async(kwargs={my_arguments}, countdown=countdown_in_secs)
      task_id = str(async_result)
```